# How can I get the result of a request after executing the request using c++ builder XE6 and Firebird?

Tags: c++, sql, firebird, dbexpress, c++builder-xe6

After connecting to a Firebird database with C++ builder, I cannot get a result from a simple select request.

I have some confusion about a lot of members of classes:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::btn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{  TSQLConnection   co = new TSQLConnection(this); 
   Base_Firebird *fb = new Base_Firebird()  ;
   bool  bl = fb->Connecter(co);   
   String sqlstring = "select nom_action from T_ACTION where CLE_ACTION=6 ";     
   if (bl)     
      TSQLQuery *req = new TSQLQuery(NULL) ;    
   req->SQLConnection = co ;
   req->SQL->Add(sqlstring);
   req->Open() ;
  }
```

My problem is here after opening the TSQLQuery, I don't know how I can get the result and execute the command.

Comment: Google and read Delphi introduction articles and books. It is a primary language of C++ Builder and its libraries, so you would get much more results of such search. Then translating after reading basic Delphi code you'd be able to write the equal basic C++ code without any significant efforts.

Comment: What is ` Base_Firebird ` ???

Comment: Base_Firebird is a object in my project that i have stated in classebase.cpp in the declartion of the class i have declared a membre wich is called 
Connecter(TSQLConnection * co)
and i'm sur is working :D

Comment: you also might look into ADO samples at https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cpp&type= /// while ADO in Delphi is not exactly what dbExpress (the lib you use) is, still the similarities should be there

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsBfIi4ofak  AnyDAC/FireDAC is considered newer library than DBX that you use *** https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/CPP/ ***
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/Category:C%2B%2B  *** https://github.com/EmbarcaderoPublic

Comment: I understood the reasoning in your code and i did the same thing in mine and it works :D
think you very mush :) :) .

Comment: This is not your real code.  It does not compile, there are several typo errors in it.

Comment: i will take a look at your links , they are interesting.
think you Remy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the end of your subroutine to something like this:

```
if (bl)    
{ /// you forgot compound operator here !!!!! 
      TSQLQuery *req = new TSQLQuery(this) ;    
   req->SQLConnection = co ;
   req->SQL->Text = sqlstring;
   req->Open() ;

   int j = 0;
   while( !req->EOF() ) 
   {
      ++j;
      String Value = req->Fields[0]->AsString;
      ShowMessageFmt( "Row %d ==> Value: %s ", ARRAYOFCONST(( j, Value )) );

      // String MSG = Format( "Row %d ==> Value: %s ", ARRAYOFCONST(( j, Value )) );
      // ShowMessage( MSG );

     req -> Next();
   };
   req->Close();
   ShowMessage("Data over.");
  }
  req -> Free();  // maybe "delete req;" would work too, dunno
}
```

To check:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Dialogs.ShowMessageFmt
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.Format
- https://osdn.net/projects/cc1101driver/scm/svn/blobs/head/trunk/VC_test/Cpp_builder_2009/Cpp_Builder_test/documents/JVC_20120502/jvcl/examples/JvProgressDialog/BCB/JvProgressDialogMain.cpp
- http://www.texttransformer.com/d2chelp/cbuilderarrayofconst.htm
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Open_Arrays#C.2B.2B_functions_that_take_open_array_arguments
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Support_for_Object_Pascal_Data_Types_and_Language_Concepts

Answer (score 0):

Read Embarcadero's documentation.  There are whole chapters on how to work the SQL components you are using, including:

[How To Perform Database Procedures](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_To_Perform_Database_Procedures)

[Navigating Datasets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Navigating_Datasets)

[Using dbExpress](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_dbExpress)

[Using dbExpress Components Index](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_dbExpress_Components_Index)

[Using TSQLQuery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_TSQLQuery)

[Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLQuery)

For example:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::btn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TSQLConnection *co = new TSQLConnection(NULL); 
    Base_Firebird *fb = new Base_Firebird();
    if (fb->Connecter(co))
    {
        TSQLQuery *req = new TSQLQuery(NULL);
        req->SQLConnection = co;
        req->SQL->Text = "select nom_action from T_ACTION where CLE_ACTION=6";
        req->Open();
        while (!req->Eof)
        {
            // use req->Fields as needed...
            req->Next();
        }
        delete req;
    }
    delete fb;
    delete co; 
}
```